# MDB and continious integration

Tags: wildfly, ibm-mq, mq

we are using Wildfly 11 and there we have some MessageQueues from 3rd party providers. We configured everything and all works fine... but the problem is, that if the 3rd party message queues are not available we receive exceptions during the enabling of our ear (which does the message listener). And this is a stupid behavior on our Jenkins Integration System because there are these 3rd party providers message queues not available.

Here is the build error what we receive during the enabling if the 3rd party MessageQueues are not available:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.1.Final:execute-commands (execute-action-scripts) on project centec-finance-manager-install: Execution execute-action-scripts of goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.1.Final:execute-commands failed: Failed to process file 'C:\Users\mleitner\git\FinanceManager\centec-finance-manager-install\target\cli\enable.cli': Command 'end-if' is invalid. {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"centec-finance-interface-arz-ear-app.ear\".\"centec-finance-interface-arz-ear-core.jar\".component.SKOSOmdb.START" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
[ERROR] Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
[ERROR] Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'Q0GT' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(17314)'.
[ERROR] Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
[ERROR] Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')."}}
```

Not installing the ear, where the MessageQueue listening is implemented, is not an option because there is other logic we want to test during our continious integration.

So what other options do we have? Install and configure some dummy queues for development would be a possible solution... but i'd rather have a configuration which forces the Wildfly to ignore that the MessageQueue of the 3rd party provider is not available. Any ideas?

Comment: Note the error `MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED` does not me the provider is not available it means your do not have access to it for some reason.  You could be denied based on the need to pass a username and password, CHLAUTH rules could be rejecting you, or the user associated with your connection has not been granted access to the queue manager or the queue/topic you are attempting to open.  This does not answer your question of how to ignore the errors for your testing but wanted to clarify the cause of the errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hin. You're right... I will check it.